# wp_query beginner

Tags: php, wp-query, wp-admin, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm really new in WP in general, but i have experineces on other PHP based CMS. How to and where to i need to implement my wp_query (see below) that triggers a product filter by category and tag out of my woocommerce products.

Basically i want to create a link in a blog post that filter products where i have offer this month.

```
$filter = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'offer_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array( 'choco-almond' ),
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array( 'offer_0617' ),
    ),
),
);$query = new WP_Query( $filter );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After you create your custom query, you just write [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The%20Loop) as you would for the default query. So your code would look like this:

```
if ( $query->have_posts() : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
   // Your Post Stuff Goes Here

endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();

else : 
   // No Posts Found Code Goes Here
endif;
```

Note the use of [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata). This is mandatory for custom queries. This function resets the post data back to the default query as URL requests are based on the default query and will load before templates.